# Prometheus - Discovering remote apps

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I have a type of remote app (.NET 8 console apps) that I want a Prometheus instance to discover/scrape.

1. Apps are short- and long-lived (seconds to days)
2. Many instances can run simultaneously
3. Are started manually
4. May run on different networks
5. Can crash, be stopped or complete
6. Can expose a Prometheus metrics endpoint: [prometheus-net](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net)

What is the appropriate architecture to discover/scrape these app instances?

I tried using [PushGateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/), however, it is unsuitable due to it never forgetting series pushed to it and exposing them indefinitely to Prometheus. When an app instance is closed (either crashed, stopped or completed), I want some of its metrics to be forgotten.

**Potential solution:**
Use PushGateway and utilize *push_time_seconds* to disregard stale data (as suggested by @markalex).

Comment: If your app runs less then a `scrape_interval` of your Prometheus what supposed to happen?

Comment: Also, how do you suppose to exposed metrics, if multiple instances are running at the same time? Do you envision some kind of port polling by your app, and getting a first free port from some pool?

Comment: I think that in this usecase prometheus is simply a wrong tool for the job. Consider any of the push-based solutions.

Comment: @markalex I am OK (actually I prefer) having unreported/unscraped metrics when instance lifespans are shorter than scrape interval.

Evidently, each app would have to use an available port if they want to expose metrics endpoints. This is a non-issue. Can you suggest any of the push-based solutions?

Comment: 1. I think influxdb and graphite are/were among popular pushed-based solutions. 2. No out-of-the-box service discovery will do what you want. But you can simply list all possible hosts with all possible ports, and allow Prometheus to handle absentees. Or you can implement your own discavery using [`http_sd_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#http_sd_config). 3. If you plan to use Pushgateway anyways, you might try use only it and handle outdated metrics with help of `push_time_seconds`.